# Calculating the angle between two lines without having to calculate the slope? (Java)

Tags: java, math, geometry, coordinates, trigonometry

I have two Lines: L1 and L2. I want to calculate the angle between the two lines. L1 has points: `{(x1, y1), (x2, y2)}` and L2 has points: `{(x3, y3), (x4, y4)}`.

How can I calculate the angle formed between these two lines, without having to calculate the slopes? The problem I am currently having is that sometimes I have horizontal lines (lines along the x-axis) and the following formula fails (divide by zero exception):

```
arctan((m1 - m2) / (1 - (m1 * m2)))
```

where `m1` and `m2` are the slopes of line 1 and line 2 respectively. Is there a formula/algorithm that can calculate the angles between the two lines without ever getting divide-by-zero exceptions? Any help would be highly appreciated.

This is my code snippet:

```
// Calculates the angle formed between two lines
public static double angleBetween2Lines(Line2D line1, Line2D line2)
{
    double slope1 = line1.getY1() - line1.getY2() / line1.getX1() - line1.getX2();
    double slope2 = line2.getY1() - line2.getY2() / line2.getX1() - line2.getX2();
    double angle = Math.atan((slope1 - slope2) / (1 - (slope1 * slope2)));
    return angle;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Remember priority of operators, you are missing parenthesis around the y1 - y2, etc...

Answer (score 100):

The `atan2` function eases the pain of dealing with `atan`.

It is declared as `double atan2(double y, double x)` and converts rectangular coordinates `(x,y)` to the angle `theta` from the polar coordinates `(r,theta)`

So I'd rewrite your code as

```
public static double angleBetween2Lines(Line2D line1, Line2D line2)
{
    double angle1 = Math.atan2(line1.getY1() - line1.getY2(),
                               line1.getX1() - line1.getX2());
    double angle2 = Math.atan2(line2.getY1() - line2.getY2(),
                               line2.getX1() - line2.getX2());
    return angle1-angle2;
}
```

Comment: i was using atan and it worked for few cases and didnt for few others

Comment: Does it calculate degrees or radians ?

Comment: @URL87 I had the same question and through trial and error determined it computes radians.

Comment: I'd replace `return angle1-angle2;` with `return Math.abs(angle1) - Math.abs(angle2);` Your version produces wrong result in lower right quadrant. Upvoted still :)

Comment: @Timo You probably meant "return Math.abs(angle1-angle2);", and then you still might want to map that into the (0, pi) range, depending on what you need it for. The result of the original version is correct, though: it give the angle you need to rotate line2, in order for it to be parallel with line1, with negative values meaning clockwise rotation.

Comment: In my case I had to use `return Math.abs(angle1) - Math.abs(angle2)`. Maybe other cases it can be different.

Comment: Works perfect and better than acos method. This answer gives directional angles and only numerical values rather than '-nan' in C++. Just a suggestion to use x2-x1 and y2-y1 instead x1-x2 and y1-y2. It doesn't make difference but just helpful convention.

Answer (score 13):

Dot product is probably more useful in this case. [Here](http://geosoft.no/software/geometry/Geometry.java.html) you can find a geometry package for Java which provides some useful helpers. Below is their calculation for determining the angle between two 3-d points. Hopefully it will get you started:

```
public static double computeAngle (double[] p0, double[] p1, double[] p2)
{
  double[] v0 = Geometry.createVector (p0, p1);
  double[] v1 = Geometry.createVector (p0, p2);

  double dotProduct = Geometry.computeDotProduct (v0, v1);

  double length1 = Geometry.length (v0);
  double length2 = Geometry.length (v1);

  double denominator = length1 * length2;

  double product = denominator != 0.0 ? dotProduct / denominator : 0.0;

  double angle = Math.acos (product);

  return angle;
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Yeah, dot product would be the way to go except doesn't creating a vector form of a line (which you need to do the dot product) basically involve getting the slope?

Answer (score 10):

```
dx1 = x2-x1;
dy1 = y2-y1;
dx2 = x4-x3;
dy2 = y4-y3;

d = dx1*dx2 + dy1*dy2;   // dot product of the 2 vectors
l2 = (dx1*dx1+dy1*dy1)*(dx2*dx2+dy2*dy2) // product of the squared lengths

angle = acos(d/sqrt(l2));
```

The dot product of 2 vectors is equal to the cosine of the angle time the length of both vectors. This computes the dot product, divides by the length of the vectors and uses the inverse cosine function to recover the angle.

Comment: This gives the magnitude but not the sign, correct?  Did anyone work out how to get the sign?  I will see what I can do . . .

Answer (score 7):

Maybe my approach for Android coordinates system will be useful for someone (used Android PointF class to store points)

```
/**
 * Calculate angle between two lines with two given points
 *
 * @param A1 First point first line
 * @param A2 Second point first line
 * @param B1 First point second line
 * @param B2 Second point second line
 * @return Angle between two lines in degrees
 */

public static float angleBetween2Lines(PointF A1, PointF A2, PointF B1, PointF B2) {
    float angle1 = (float) Math.atan2(A2.y - A1.y, A1.x - A2.x);
    float angle2 = (float) Math.atan2(B2.y - B1.y, B1.x - B2.x);
    float calculatedAngle = (float) Math.toDegrees(angle1 - angle2);
    if (calculatedAngle < 0) calculatedAngle += 360;
    return calculatedAngle;
}
```

It return positive value in degrees for any quadrant: 0 <= x < 360

You can checkout my [utility class here](https://github.com/dehimb/Geometry)

Answer (score 3):

The formula for getting the angle is `tan a = (slope1-slope2)/(1+slope1*slope2)`

You are using:

```
tan a = (slope1 - slope2) / (1 - slope1 * slope2)
```

So it should be:

```
double angle = Math.atan((slope1 - slope2) / (1 + slope1 * slope2));
```

Answer (score 0):

First, are you sure the brackets are in the right order? I think (could be wrong) it should be this:

```
   double slope1 = (line1.getY1() - line1.getY2()) / (line1.getX1() - line1.getX2());
   double slope2 = (line2.getY1() - line2.getY2()) / (line2.getX1() - line2.getX2());
```

Second, there are two things you could do for the div by zero: you could catch the exception and handle it

```
double angle;
try
{
    angle = Math.atan((slope1 - slope2) / (1 - (slope1 * slope2)));
catch (DivideByZeroException dbze)
{
    //Do something about it!
}
```

...or you could check that your divisors are never zero *before* you attempt the operation.

```
if ((1 - (slope1 * slope2))==0)
{
    return /*something meaningful to avoid the div by zero*/
}
else 
{
    double angle = Math.atan((slope1 - slope2) / (1 - (slope1 * slope2)));
    return angle;
 }
```

Comment: Yeah sorry, forgot to add the brackets. But I mean, I don't really want to catch the exception because I dont need the slope in the first place. Even if I know if the line is horizontal, I didnt get the angle yet. I just need the angle between the two lines.

Comment: @jNoob: if you don't want to catch the exception, then just check the divisors before any division operation.

Answer (score 0):

Check this Python code:

```
import math
def angle(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3):

  if (x1==x2==x3 or y1==y2==y3):
    return 180
  else:
    dx1 = x2-x1
    dy1 = y2-y1
    dx2 = x3-x2
    dy2 = y3-y2
    if x1==x2:
      a1=90
    else:
      m1=dy1/dx1
      a1=math.degrees(math.atan(m1))
    if x2==x3:
      a2=90
    else:
      m2=dy2/dx2
      a2=math.degrees(math.atan(m2))
    angle = abs(a2-a1)
    return angle

print angle(0,4,0,0,9,-6)
```

Comment: How can this be correct when 4 points are given

Answer (score 0):

```
dx1=x2-x1 ; dy1=y2-y1 ; dx2=x4-x3 ;dy2=y4-y3.

Angle(L1,L2)=pi()/2*((1+sign(dx1))* (1-sign(dy1^2))-(1+sign(dx2))*(1-sign(dy2^2)))
           +pi()/4*((2+sign(dx1))*sign(dy1)-(2+sign(dx2))*sign(dy2))
           +sign(dx1*dy1)*atan((abs(dx1)-abs(dy1))/(abs(dx1)+abs(dy1)))
           -sign(dx2*dy2)*atan((abs(dx2)-abs(dy2))/(abs(dx2)+abs(dy2)))
```