# Math Calculation to retrieve angle between two points?

Tags: c#, math, distance, angle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to calculate the angle between two points relative to the horizontal axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586063/how-to-calculate-the-angle-between-two-points-relative-to-the-horizontal-axis)

I've been looking for this for ages and it's just really annoying me so I've decided to just ask...

Provided I have two points (namely x1, y1, and x2, y2), I would like to calculate the angle between these two points, presuming that when y1 == y2 and x1 > x2 the angle is 180 degrees...

I have the below code that I have been working with (using knowledge from high school) and I just can't seem to produce the desired result.

```
float xDiff = x1 - x2;
float yDiff = y1 - y2;
return (float)Math.Atan2(yDiff, xDiff) * (float)(180 / Math.PI);
```

Thanks in advance, I'm getting so frustrated...

Comment: I would suggest you ask this on http://math.stackexchange.com/ - although I'm sure there are plenty here capable of giving you a decent answer it's not strictly a programming question.

Comment: you can't find a angle between two points. Two lines, yes. So presumably you mean to use the xaxis as the other line.

Comment: What? "when x1 == x2 and x1 > x2" - when is that ever true?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I guess that should be an OR but it still doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, the x1 == x2 is meant to be y1 == y2.  I know this question doesn't particularly belong here but I honestly didn't know math.stackexchange.com existed until 6 seconds prior to be writing this... If anyone could help, I'd be forever grateful..

Comment: arctan( y1 - y2 / x1 - x2 ) gives you the angle between PQ and X-axis, where P and Q are your points. If you want the "angle between these two points", which means the angle substended by these two points on the origin, you want arctan( y1 / x1 ) - arctan( y2 / x2 )

Comment: Maybe you need to slow down and actually carefully describe the problem you're trying to solve - define what you mean by "the angle" (as @MitchWheat points out, two points just describe a line segment)

Comment: In what direction do you want the angle increasing? Clockwise or anticlockwise?

Comment: Well, provided we had a line the joined the two points, when the line is completely horizontal and the x1,y1 point is on the left and the x2,y2 point is on the right, the angle is 0 degrees.  The angle will increase in a clockwise direction?

Comment: This link is related to java but i think this will help you   http://stackoverflow.com/q/3365171/1577396

Answer (score 32, accepted):

From what I've gathered, you want the following to hold:

- Horizontal line: `P1 -------- P2` => 0°
- Horizontal line: `P2 -------- P1` => 180°

### Rotating the horizontal line clockwise

You said, you want the angle to increase in clockwise direction.

Rotating this line `P1 -------- P2` such that `P1` is above `P2`, the angle must thus be 90°.

If, however, we rotated in the opposite direction, `P1` would be below `P2` and the angle is -90° or 270°.

### Working with `atan2`

**Basis**: Considering `P1` to be the origin and measuring the angle of `P2` relative to the origin, then `P1 -------- P2` will correctly yield `0`.

```
float xDiff = x2 - x1;
float yDiff = y2 - y1;
return Math.Atan2(yDiff, xDiff) * 180.0 / Math.PI;
```

However, `atan2` let's the angle increase in CCW direction.
Rotating in CCW direction around the origin, `y` goes through the following values:

- y = 0
- y > 0
- y = 0
- y < 0
- y = 0

This means, that we can simply invert the sign of `y` to flip the direction. But because C#'s coordinates increase from top to bottom, the sign is already reversed when computing `yDiff`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but when applied in C# it doesn't work at all.  The current example I have is the first point being a fixed point (say 32, 32) and the second point being the x and y location of the mouse relative to the form.  The code you provided returns either a 90 degree angle or -90 degree angle...

Comment: I have tested the code locally in VisualStudio now. Apart from forgetting that Coordinates in Windows go from top to bottom, the code is working correctly.

Comment: @Aeaex, when you are testing new code like this, don't try it with the mouse first, try it with a couple of numbers. And if, by mistake, you try it with the mouse first and it doesn't work, don't go straight to the forum to complain, try it with a couple of numbers.

Comment: @Beta Your completely right , it was a mistake made on my part.  The code works.  Also, thank you for your post phant0m.  Helped a lot.

Comment: @Aeaex Speaking about that code, I do wonder why it says `x2` twice in that subtraction, especially considering it doesn't in the JavaScript I used and nor does it in my VisualStudio code -.-

Comment: @phant0m Which code excerpt are you referring to?

Comment: @Aeaex Look at the latest edit I made. Btw, you don't need to @ username when you want to notify the owner of a post ;)