# Collision of two balls in wpf and getting the paths of colliding balls

Tags: c#, wpf, collision

This question is regarding WPF.

I have two balls, one static and the other is moving towards the static ball. On collision the balls would move in the direction that would be decided by the collision that at which angle they would collide and move accordingly.

My question is basically for suggestions for what is the easiest and the most effective way of colliding the objects in WPF and after collision giving them a path to move accordingly. Apart from deceleration etc, what should be the best strategy that should be applied to DETECT collision and GIVE NEW PATHS TO THE BALLS AFTER COLLISION.

Comment: **Close-Voting:** *Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist*

Comment: Your are very true about it sir but i asked for SUGGESTIONS as it is clearly written in my description

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ball to Ball Collision - Detection and Handling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/345838/ball-to-ball-collision-detection-and-handling)

Comment: i have read all collision questions here but i could not get any information on how to get the new paths of collided balls IN "WPF". What functions or properties are actually used to determine them.

Comment: @GarryVass if you could possibly tell me how to get it all done in WPF i would really appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply figure out the distance of the centers of the 2 balls.

```
if (distance(ball1.Center, ball2.Center) <= ball1.Radius + ball2.Radius) 
{
    // collision
}
```

For the distance use this:

```
double x = ball1.Center.X - ball2.Center.X;
double y = ball1.Center.Y - ball2.Center.Y;
double distance = Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y); // pythagoras
```

For calculating the new directions you'll need some more math. Have a look for a geometrics library like it is delivered with XNA. Try googeling your question again and use XNA in the search instead of WPF - this will solve your problem, i guess.

Comment: Or don't calculate this on your own and just write `(ball1.Center - ball2.Center).Length` (from [Vector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Vector.aspx)).

Comment: That's true. Using built-in methods are aven better and less error-prone. I didn't use WPF for years and did not know about the existence of the Vector class until now. 
If it works like the Vector class of XNA, it's a a full scale toolkit for all your needs. :)

Comment: @rulebot i am restricted to WPF only. XNA is not an option right now.

Comment: Hi,
mathematics and geometry works the same way in WPF and XNA ;)
This is just a quite common question in the XNA community.

Comment: Alright, i have an idea can you help me out in this? if i have a ball colliding with an other, the both will collide on some point, meaning some point on their circumference. If i can stretch a line from that point through the center of the ball, will it do the direction part easily?

Comment: Did you look for this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/345838/ball-to-ball-collision-detection-and-handling
It was posted in the answer below. I guess the second animation does represent your answer?! You'll need some basic Vector Math, better watch out for a geometry lib - it's faster than re-inventing the wheel ;)

Comment: No problem. I hope it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

I would calculate the distance (pythagoras) between them, if the distance is smaller than the two radius added, a collision occurs.

Check here for the angle between the points:
[Math Calculation to retrieve angle between two points?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12891516/math-calculation-to-retrieve-angle-between-two-points)

You could check this one:
[Ball to Ball Collision - Detection and Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345838/ball-to-ball-collision-detection-and-handling)

Comment: i appreciate your answer sir but could you please explain that? i mean collision part is fine, but how would you suggest me that i should work on getting the paths AFTER their collision has taken place?

Comment: Did you read the second link? I think there's a great explaination there.