# Get the angle and the distance of point from center point

Tags: c#, math, geometry, distance, angle

I'm trying to make a color picker and need some help, I need to get an angle of a point from a center point, starting from the top moving to the left, highest value being 1 and the lowest 0, as well as distance between the two points;

I skipped math in high school so I'm at a loss, any help would be appreciated

[image]

Comment: ARTAN[(Y(P)-Y(C)/(X(P)-X(C))] and SQRT[((X(P)-X(C))^2 + ((Y(P)-Y(C))^2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to find angle between center and the point in radians:

```
Math.Atan2(point.y-center.y,point.x-center.x)
```

normalize it:

```
Math.Atan2(point.y-center.y,point.x-center.x)/Math.PI/2
```

make it start from top:

```
Math.Atan2(point.y-center.y,point.x-center.x)/Math.PI/2+0.25
```

don't let it go below zero:

```
(Math.Atan2(point.y-center.y,point.x-center.x)/Math.PI/2+0.25+1)%1
```

invert it so it goes counterclockwise:

```
1-(Math.Atan2(point.y-center.y,point.x-center.x)/Math.PI/2+0.25+1)%1
```

you can rewrite it as:

```
1-(Math.Atan2(point.y-center.y,point.x-center.x)/2/Math.PI+1.25)%1
```

Comment: Math.Atan2 is described here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12891516/math-calculation-to-retrieve-angle-between-two-points)