# Android Calculate angle between two lines on a custom image

Tags: android, android-canvas, lines, angle

I have a custom view with an image taken from mobile gallery and then using canvas I draw circles at the point of touch. In my app, user would be able to touch any three points say A, B, C and draw lines AB and BC using Path functionality. But how can I find the angle between the lines AB and BC. I need to measure Angle ABC and Angle ACB in degrees. Any help would be appreciated. thanks.

Comment: do you see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365171/calculating-the-angle-between-two-lines-without-having-to-calculate-the-slope ?

Comment: I saw that. I want to draw both inner angle and outer angle. How can I draw on either sides of the lines ?